# Auto scale MongoDB Community Operator Replicaset

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, hpa

I have three node mongodb cluster in GCP and it was deployed using MongoDB Community Operator. It is working fine. I need to setup auto scaling feature. I tried it with HPA Kubernetes object.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: mongodb-hpa
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  minReplicas: 3
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: mongodb-dev
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
```

HPA is collect stats and try to scale up/down. But created pod suddenly delete in scale up and again change to 3.

Is this done by operator ?

How I achieve this auto scaling feature?

Answer (score 0):

Is this done by operator ? yes
If you look up log of operator Pod, you can find that, operator scale down statefulset(mongo).

You should apply new yaml.
see https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/deploy-configure.md#scale-a-replica-set